# How to host NuGet packages locally?

Tags: nuget

I am writing framework components for a project I am working on and I'm wondering if it's possible to host a NuGet package locally without a server so I'll be able to create a full release cycle just by using my computer.
If it's possible, please explain how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular folder. More info here:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds